# PHP: mysqli and prepared statement, failing if a field is empty

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am using mysqli to insert a new row into a table.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (field1, field2) VALUES (?, ?)");
```

field 1 and 2 come from a post request.

But if field 2 is not set the entire row is not inserted, how can I change this behaviour so it still inserts field 1.

Comment: Is your schema for this table saying the field2 cannot be null?

Comment: change your default column  setting of field2 --> None from Null

Comment: While testing any script using `MYSQLI_` Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: In future, if you are asking about code that does not work or has an issue, it is a _good idea to post the code as well as a description of your problem_

Comment: @RiggsFolly You are correct, none of the fields could null, and it appears that I was trying to insert null where the input field was not set. Changing those fields to allow null results in the correct behaviour. This confused me because I previously did not use prepared statements which inserted the same data fine.

Comment: @Mar _I previously did not use prepared statements which inserted the same data fine_ I dont think so. MYSQL controls this and it would not make a difference if you were using prepared statements or not

Comment: My previous query that I was switching to a prepared statement looked like this $log_query = "INSERT INTO table SET
                      field1 = '$field1',
                      field2 = 'field2';";
 mysqli_query($con, $log_query); Which was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this behavior by allowing Null value for field 2 in Database. Or you can assign an empty string to the variable if it is NULL.

```
 if(!(isset($_POST['field2']))
        {
          $field2="";
        }
        else
        {
          $field2=$_POST['field2']);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, allowing null in the database schema worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first you check field is set or not set

```
if(!(isset($_POST['field2']))
        {
          $field2="";
        }
        else
        {
          $field2=$_POST['field2']);
        }

    //and then you execute the query
```